# Symfony UniqueEntity Constraint and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

i'm new to symfony, and don't know much about javascript!

i created a symfony form, and added a UniqueEntity constraint on the name and firstname, so it's not possible to add a same person twice in the database.

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"firstname","name"}, message="this person already exists")
```

it works pretty well!
but in this case, i would like symfony to show me a javascript window with a message and 2 choices. for example: "joe smiley already exists! would you like to add an homonym? yes / no

does anyone know how to do this?

Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this validation is strictly server-side.

You should try some `JS` validation libraries like: http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/ (just an example)

Answer (score 0):

well you could try to find if is there and error message for that field, and that will depend on how are you displaying your form fields, i strongly strongly recommend you to customize your form rendering to suit your needs, here is and example of what can you do.

```
    <div class="control-group {% if(form_errors(form.descripcion)|length) %} error {% endif %} ">
        {{ form_label(form.descripcion, null, { 'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'} }) }}
        <div class="controls">
            {{ form_widget(form.descripcion) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.descripcion) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

that will render this when the validation shows and error message

```
    <div class="control-group  error  ">
        <label class="control-label required" for="AreaComercio_descripcion">Descripcion</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="AreaComercio_descripcion" name="AreaComercio[descripcion]" required="required" >
            <span class="help-inline">This value should not be blank.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so you have to ask if is there an span sibling with the class help-inline if you dont know how to custimze your form rendering take a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) and another advice use jquery, there are lots of people using it, jquery have an strong comunity that will help you if you are in the need, that said, i will use jquery to ilustrate what you can do to solve your problem.

```
if($("#AreaComercio_descripcion ~ .help-inline").length) { // here using sibling selector filter to ask if there a siblig with the class help-inline
    var invalid_value = $("#AreaComercio_descripcion").val(); // asking for the field value thru its id attribute
    confirm(invalid_value+" already exists! would you like to add an homonym ?");
}
```

using javascript confirm is the easiest way to do what you want but you can use other more flexible options like [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or you could try to install [twitter bootstrap](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle) in your symfony installation, well i guess thats all i hope it will be usefull to you